# delphi xe3 database with MySQL version 5.1 Error. Exception TDBXError in module. Unable to load dbxmys.dll (errorCode126)

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe3, dbexpress

I have droped all components to the form in order to make a simple database application. The connection was successfully tested. After setting the properties of the Components and running the application, the message is displayed.

"Exception TDBXError in module project6.exe at 00218766. Unable to load dbxmys.dll (errorCode126). It may be missing from the system path."

I have installed delphi xe3 in "C:\delphi xe3". dbxmys.dll exists in C:\delphi xe3\bin but again This error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have Delphi installed and the `dbxmys.dll` DLL in `C:\delphi xe3\bin` your application `project6.exe` can not find the DLL, this is because your application does not know where to look for it.

[According Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx) your application will look for the DLL in the flowing places

- The directory where the executable module for the current process is
  located.
- The current directory.
- The Windows system directory.
- The Windows directory.
- The directories listed in the PATH environment variable.

So unless `C:\delphi xe3\bin` is named in the PATH environment variable, you will need to copy the DLL to one of the above locations. (On my PC `C:\Program Files\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\bin` is in the PATH variable)

As you will probably need to distribute the DLL with your application, copying it to the same folder as `project6.exe` should fix this.

The reason you can connect to MySQL when using the IDE is because the Delphi IDE is running in or knows about `C:\delphi xe3\bin`

Comment: Thanks . got to know it now.